# `stack build` failed with `/usr/bin/ld: final link failed` on Archlinux

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm trying to use the `req` package (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/req) in a Haskell project, with stack.

So far, I've done `stack new my-project`, `stack setup`, `stack build` and `stack exec my-project-exe` all fine.

Have added `req` to the cabal file like so:

```
name:                my-project
version:             0.1.0.0
synopsis:            Short description of your package
homepage:            https://github.com/githubuser/#readme
license:             BSD3
license-file:        LICENSE
author:              Author name here
maintainer:          example@example.com
copyright:           2017 Author name here
category:            Web
build-type:          Simple
extra-source-files:  README.md
cabal-version:       >=1.10


library
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  exposed-modules:     Lib
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
                     , req   -- THIS IS THE LINE IVE ADDED
  default-language:    Haskell2010

executable my-project-exe
  hs-source-dirs:      app
  main-is:             Main.hs
  ghc-options:         -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  build-depends:       base
                     , my-project
  default-language:    Haskell2010

test-suite my-project-test
  type:                exitcode-stdio-1.0
  hs-source-dirs:      test
  main-is:             Spec.hs
  build-depends:       base
                     , my-project
  ghc-options:         -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  default-language:    Haskell2010

source-repository head
  type:     git
  location: https://github.com/githubuser/my-project
```

And finally, cut and paste the example from the req readme into `src/Lib.hs`, changing the function name like so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings    #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-orphans #-}

module Lib 
    ( someFunc
    ) where

import Control.Exception (throwIO)
import Network.HTTP.Req
import Data.Aeson

-- Just make your monad stack an instance of MonadHttp in your application
-- and start making requests, enjoy automatic connection sharing.

instance MonadHttp IO where
  handleHttpException = throwIO

someFunc :: IO ()
someFunc = do
  let payload = object
        [ "foo" .= (10 :: Int)
        , "bar" .= (20 :: Int) ]
  -- One function, full power and flexibility.
  r <- req POST -- method
    (https "httpbin.org" /: "post") -- safe by construction URL
    (ReqBodyJson payload) -- use built-in options or add your own
    jsonResponse -- specify how to interpret response
    mempty       -- query params, headers, explicit port number, etc.
  print (responseBody r :: Value)
```

And now `stack build` is erroring:

```
%> stack build
basement-0.0.4: configure
basement-0.0.4: build
zlib-0.6.1.2: configure
aeson-1.1.2.0: download
zlib-0.6.1.2: build
network-2.6.3.2: configure
th-lift-instances-0.1.11: download
aeson-1.1.2.0: configure
aeson-1.1.2.0: build
th-lift-instances-0.1.11: configure
th-lift-instances-0.1.11: build
th-lift-instances-0.1.11: copy/register
aeson-1.1.2.0: copy/register
Progress: 5/28
--  While building package network-2.6.3.2 using:
      /tmp/stack7830/network-2.6.3.2/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup/setup --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0 configure --with-ghc=/home/liam/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/bin/ghc --with-ghc-pkg=/home/liam/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/bin/ghc-pkg --user --package-db=clear --package-db=global --package-db=/home/liam/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/lts-9.14/8.0.2/pkgdb --libdir=/home/liam/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/lts-9.14/8.0.2/lib --bindir=/home/liam/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/lts-9.14/8.0.2/bin --datadir=/home/liam/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/lts-9.14/8.0.2/share --libexecdir=/home/liam/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/lts-9.14/8.0.2/libexec --sysconfdir=/home/liam/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/lts-9.14/8.0.2/etc --docdir=/home/liam/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/lts-9.14/8.0.2/doc/network-2.6.3.2 --htmldir=/home/liam/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/lts-9.14/8.0.2/doc/network-2.6.3.2 --haddockdir=/home/liam/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/lts-9.14/8.0.2/doc/network-2.6.3.2 --dependency=base=base-4.9.1.0 --dependency=bytestring=bytestring-0.10.8.1 --dependency=unix=unix-2.7.2.1
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: /home/liam/code/forecast-compare/.stack-work/logs/network-2.6.3.2.log

    [1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( /tmp/stack7830/network-2.6.3.2/Setup.hs, /tmp/stack7830/network-2.6.3.2/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup/Main.o )
    [2 of 2] Compiling StackSetupShim   ( /home/liam/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.hs, /tmp/stack7830/network-2.6.3.2/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup/StackSetupShim.o )
    Linking /tmp/stack7830/network-2.6.3.2/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup/setup ...
    Configuring network-2.6.3.2...
    configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-compiler
    checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    checking for gcc... /usr/bin/gcc
    checking whether the C compiler works... yes
    checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
    checking for suffix of executables... 
    checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/tmp/stack7830/network-2.6.3.2':
    configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
    If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
    See `config.log' for more details


--  While building package zlib-0.6.1.2 using:
      /home/liam/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0 build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: /home/liam/code/forecast-compare/.stack-work/logs/zlib-0.6.1.2.log

    Configuring zlib-0.6.1.2...
    Building zlib-0.6.1.2...
    Preprocessing library zlib-0.6.1.2...
    /usr/bin/ld: .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/Codec/Compression/Zlib/Stream_hsc_make.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
    /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    linking .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/Codec/Compression/Zlib/Stream_hsc_make.o failed (exit code 1)
    command was: /usr/bin/gcc .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/Codec/Compression/Zlib/Stream_hsc_make.o .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/Codec/Compression/Zlib/Stream_hsc_utils.o -o .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/Codec/Compression/Zlib/Stream_hsc_make -fno-PIE -fno-stack-protector -lz -L/home/liam/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/bytestring-0.10.8.1 -Wl,-R,/home/liam/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/bytestring-0.10.8.1 -L/home/liam/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/deepseq-1.4.2.0 -Wl,-R,/home/liam/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/deepseq-1.4.2.0 -L/home/liam/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/array-0.5.1.1 -Wl,-R,/home/liam/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/array-0.5.1.1 -L/home/liam/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/base-4.9.1.0 -Wl,-R,/home/liam/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/base-4.9.1.0 -L/home/liam/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/integer-gmp-1.0.0.1 -Wl,-R,/home/liam/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/integer-gmp-1.0.0.1 -lgmp -L/home/liam/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/ghc-prim-0.5.0.0 -Wl,-R,/home/liam/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/ghc-prim-0.5.0.0 -L/home/liam/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/rts -Wl,-R,/home/liam/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/rts -lm -lrt -ldl -lpthread


--  While building package basement-0.0.4 using:
      /home/liam/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0 build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: /home/liam/code/forecast-compare/.stack-work/logs/basement-0.0.4.log

    Configuring basement-0.0.4...
    Building basement-0.0.4...
    Preprocessing library basement-0.0.4...
    /usr/bin/ld: .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/Basement/Terminal/Size_hsc_make.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
    /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    linking .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/Basement/Terminal/Size_hsc_make.o failed (exit code 1)
    command was: /usr/bin/gcc .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/Basement/Terminal/Size_hsc_make.o .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/Basement/Terminal/Size_hsc_utils.o -o .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/Basement/Terminal/Size_hsc_make -fno-PIE -fno-stack-protector -L/home/liam/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/base-4.9.1.0 -Wl,-R,/home/liam/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/base-4.9.1.0 -L/home/liam/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/integer-gmp-1.0.0.1 -Wl,-R,/home/liam/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/integer-gmp-1.0.0.1 -lgmp -L/home/liam/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/ghc-prim-0.5.0.0 -Wl,-R,/home/liam/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/ghc-prim-0.5.0.0 -L/home/liam/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/rts -Wl,-R,/home/liam/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/rts -lm -lrt -ldl -lpthread
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Are you using archlinux? Try installing ncurses5-compat-libs from the AUR, and adding `ghc-build: nopie` to your stack.yaml, or if you want to prevent this happening in other projects, add it to your `~/.stack/config.yaml`

Comment: I am indeed using arch Linux --- should have mentioned that but didn't think that'd be related! Thanks, this worked!

Comment: Great! I added a slightly more in depth answer to hopefully help any other users who come across this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been plaguing users of Arch Linux for a few months. It appears to be related to the ncurses library, and possibly due to Arch Linux dynamically linking Haskell packages, whilst most (all?) other distros use static linking.

The current work around involves using the `ghc-build: nopie` option for the stack ghc version, and installing [`ncurses5-compat-libs`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ncurses5-compat-libs/) from the AUR.

If you wish to set this globally, you can set it in your `~/.stack/config.yaml`, so it applies to all projects you build with stack.

A bug report is currently open [here](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/56101), and some related discussion can be found on the [arch forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=230091) or the [stack github](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3509).

Answer (score 1):

For me deleting `~/.stack` and using

```
stack setup --ghc-build=ncurses6
```

and adding

```
ghc-build: ncurses6
```

to

```
~/.stack/config.yaml
```

resolved this.

Addendum:

```
ghc-build: tinfo6
```

and

```
stack setup --ghc-build=tinfo6
```

worked even better for me.